# In which books can I read about the supernal realms?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Which books contain the best details on the supernal realms (Arcadia and such)? The Mage core book is light on these kinds of details, but someone told me that one of the expansions gets pretty depthy on this. I've considered taking a chronicle to one of them, but I feel like my knowledge of them is rather light.

**update:** worth noting this isn't necessarily a mage specific chronicle

Comment: Based on your _Mage: the Awakening_ tag, I've retagged this with our New World of Darkness tag. If that's incorrect and it's about the Old World of Darkness system, change this from the **nwod** tag to the **owod** tag. Welcome to the site!

Comment: This diagram may be of intrest.
http://willworks.deviantart.com/art/New-World-of-Darkness-Cosmology-Map-drawing-309999687

The books are (intentionally) not fully concrete with what is going on the the realms.

Also it would help to know what ou are playing as. Eg Mages going in the flesh to various supernal realms is different from anyone else going to them, in terms of what is interesting.
(Also changeling are different also, see equinox road)

Comment: @Oxinabox currently I've got players templating mortals, and will be letting them pick templates later, ending up in a another world is a path I've considered.

Comment: The Supernal Realms are generally not the kinda place peple just wander into.
The Superal Realms are on the other side of the Abyss. Only Godlike beings (eg Accending Mages) cross the abyss, in the flesh.

(Arcadia is a bit weird, because changeling reasons).

Normally if you leave this realm you are bound for one of the other realms in the Fallen World.
The Shadow, the Hedge, or the Underworld. (Technically also the Inferno, but that is only mentioned in passing, so not interesting for this question).

Course it is your game, so you can do what you want.

Comment: Perhaps if you want an excuse to visit the supernal an archmage could send you there, out of curiosity or otherwise

Comment: this is all kind of pending what information is available (and my budget), I may of course just be doing arcadia, or none of the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure there isn't an even deeper treatise out there on the Supernal realms, but I think [**Tome of the Watchtowers**](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/3792/Tome-of-the-Watchtowers-A-Guide-to-Paths), a **Mage: The Awakening** sourcebook is an excellent starting point, and might just be what you're looking for. The book examines the Paths in detail, and takes a thorough look at the individual Realms associated with each of the Paths as well.

Alternatively, for a quicker and more accessible introduction you could check out the [Supernal Realm(s)](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Supernal_Realm) entry of Wikia's White Wolf section, which draws a lot from the book mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Entering and interacting with the Supernal Realms is an essential element of becoming and playing an archmaster. As a result, the **[Imperial Mysteries](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/97925/Imperial-Mysteries?term=imperial%20mysteries)** book is full of concrete details that would be appropriate for that sort of chronicle.